# how to setup sysroot in setup.py for cython

Tags: python, cython

I am compiling a simple cython example under mac OSX 10.7.
The compiler keeps using -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk ....
I suppose 10.7.sdk will be used instead. Why setup.py can not figure out which sdk to use?
Any comments? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The cpython installation assumes an older version of xcode on MacOSX 10.6. If you need to use SDK for 10.7 from a newer version of Xcode (4.3.3), you will need to do

```
export CFLAGS=-sysroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
export LDFLAGS=-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib
```

because you execute

```
python setup.py
```